# How to do click on specific screen text?

Tags: c#, text, automation, click, screen

Do you know how to do click on a specific screen text?

I need to do click on a text inside a GUI Object from a external application; I need to automate this with C#. What is the reference that I need to this? I'm new in C#

Comment: What kind of application is it

Comment: Could MacroExpress be an option (depending what kind of automating you're doing).

Comment: I need test the application with WPF, is for software testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn two tricks to accomplish this:

1. How to find the `HWND` (the handle) to the window that you want to send the click event to. There are some APIs in the Forms namespace to help with this or you can use PInvoke.
2. How to send the appropriate windows messages (`WM_MOUSEDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEUP`) using `SendMessage`.

Put these two together and you should be able to simulate a click event.